# Sum up numbers from matching multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have an excel table like this named `data`:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ Dist ║ Place ║ Type    ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║ 394  ║ Inner ║ Asphalt ║
║ 123  ║ Inner ║ Asphalt ║
║ 823  ║ Outer ║ Dirt    ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

I want to return the sum of `Dist` (394+123), which is placed `Inner` and has the `Asphalt` type, in a new table (separate from this one), which looks like this:

```
╔═════════╦══════════╗
║         ║ Inner    ║
╠═════════╬══════════╣
║ Asphalt ║ =FORMULA ║
╚═════════╩══════════╝
```

I tried with this formula, but it doesn't work:

```
=
INDEX(
    SUM(data!A:A);
    MATCH(A2&B1; data!$C:$C & data!$B:$B; 0)
)
```

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try,

```
=sumifs(data!a:a, data!b:b, b$1, data!c:c, $a2)
```

Comment: Thank You very much, solved it!  `b$1` and `$a2` are nice touch also. :)